# Java program to sort a versioning string in an ascending order

Tags: java, sorting, versioning

I have a list containing version strings, such as things:

```
List<String> versions_list = Arrays.asList("1.1.2", "1.0.0", "1.3.3", "1.0.12", "1.0.2");
```

I would like to sort it, so the result would be something like this:

```
["1.0.0", "1.0.2", "1.0.12", "1.1.2", "1.3.3"]
```

How to do this in Java.

Comment: First of all, provide a valid Java code.

Comment: Is version guaranteed to always be in form `A.B.C` or versions like `A.B` or `A.B.C.D` are also possible?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a *modern* solution, using `Comparator.comparing` to build a version string comparator, based on the pre-existing standard library `Arrays.compare(int[])` method.

```
    List<String> versionList = Arrays.asList("1.1.2", "1.0.0", "1.3.3", "1.0.12", "1.0.2");

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\.");
    Comparator<String> versionComparator = Comparator.comparing(
        str -> pattern.splitAsStream(str)
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .toArray(),
        Arrays::compare);
    versionList.sort(versionComparator);
    
    System.out.println(versionList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) as shown below:

```
    List<String> sorted = List.of("1.1.2", "1.0.0", "1.3.3", "1.0.12", "1.0.2")
            .stream()
            .sorted((s1, s2) -> {
                String[] s1Parts = s1.split("\\.");
                String[] s2Parts = s2.split("\\.");

                Integer[] s1IntParts = Arrays.stream(s1Parts).map(Integer::parseInt).toArray(Integer[]::new);
                Integer[] s2IntParts = Arrays.stream(s2Parts).map(Integer::parseInt).toArray(Integer[]::new);

                int comparisonResult = -1;
                for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                    comparisonResult = Integer.compare(s1IntParts[i], s2IntParts[i]);
                    if (comparisonResult != 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return comparisonResult;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] versions_list = {"1.1.2", "1.0.0", "1.3.3", "1.0.12", "1.0.2"};
    Arrays.sort(versions_list, (o1, o2) -> {
        String[] str1 = o1.split("\\.");
        String[] str2 = o2.split("\\.");
        if (!Integer.valueOf(str1[0]).equals(Integer.valueOf(str2[0])))
            return Integer.valueOf(str1[0]) - Integer.valueOf(str2[0]);
        if (!Integer.valueOf(str1[1]).equals(Integer.valueOf(str2[1])))
            return Integer.valueOf(str1[1]) - Integer.valueOf(str2[1]);
        return Integer.valueOf(str1[2]) - Integer.valueOf(str2[2]);
    });
    for (String str : versions_list) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

sorry，I wirte code again
output：1.0.0   1.0.2   1.0.12   1.1.2  1.3.3, you also use cycle to do it!

Comment: Do not repost a new answer.  Simply correct your old one.

Comment: ok，I am fresher.

Comment: Should  I edit my old answer?

Comment: No.  Not this time.  Don't worry about.  And welcome to Stack Overflow.  :)

Comment: ok,thank you! I remember it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
List<String> versions = Arrays.asList("1.1.2", "1.0.0", "1.3.3", "1.0.12", "1.0.2");
```

You should use a custom `Comparator` as long as the default comparator cannot be applied to this type of the String, otherwise the numbers will not be sorted numerically (ex, `12` is considered lower than `2`.

```
versions.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final String l, final String r) {
        String[] left = l.split("\\.");
        String[] right = r.split("\\.");
        int iterableLength = Math.min(left.length, right.length);
        for (int i=0; i<iterableLength; i++) {
            if (!left[i].equals(right[i])) {
                return Integer.parseInt(left[i]) - Integer.parseInt(right[i]);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
});
```

... using a lambda expression ...

```
versions.sort((l, r) -> {
    String[] left = l.split("\\.");
    String[] right = r.split("\\.");
    int iterableLength = Math.min(left.length, right.length);
    for (int i=0; i<iterableLength; i++) {
        if (!left[i].equals(right[i])) {
            return Integer.parseInt(left[i]) - Integer.parseInt(right[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
});
```

This is a very straightforward solution using Regex to split the version notation into 3 separate parts. Each part not equal to another is a subject for the numeric comparison, hence `Integer.parseInt(String)` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using a lambda of the Comparator.  Takes care of varying length version ids.

```
Comparator<String> comp = (a, b) -> {
    String[] aa = a.split("\\.");
    String[] bb = b.split("\\.");
    int r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(aa.length, bb.length); i++) {
        r = Integer
                .compare(Integer.valueOf(aa[i]),Integer.valueOf(bb[i]));
        if (r != 0) {
            return r;
        }
    }
    return Integer.compare(aa.length, bb.length);
};
            
List<String> versions_list = Arrays.asList("1.1.2", "1.0.0",
        "1.3.3", "1.0.12", "1.0.0.12", "1.1.0.2", "1.0.2", "1.2.1.2.3");
versions_list.sort(comp);
System.out.println(versions_list);
```

Prints

```
[1.0.0, 1.0.0.12, 1.0.2, 1.0.12, 1.1.0.2, 1.1.2, 1.2.1.2.3, 1.3.3]
```